# Custom fonts in static html in Android app

Tags: android, fonts, webview

I have a fragment that has a webview in it that I load with static HTML from the assets folder. I want to use a combination of Roboto and Roboto Light for the font in this html. How should I do that?

I have downloaded the Roboto fonts from Google Fonts but I do not know where to put them or how to reference them. I want this to work offline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use `CSS` for that. create `CSS` style for `html` file and use this code in that.

In `CSS` file.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'font';
    src: url('fonts/font.ttf');
}
```

In `html`

```
<div class="body" >

your doucumention

</div>
```

in `CSS`

```
.body{

font-family:font;

}
```

Use this inside head tag in html file to link it with css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourcss.css" type="text/css" />
```

Hope be useful for you.

Comment: So i should store the font under assets/font/? Is this also where fonts not used by css should be stored?